# Не работает map

Tags: map, xhtml, html

Раньше не приходилось работать с этими тэгами, уже голову сломал, не могу понять, почему не работает. Спозиционировал картинку, координаты всех углов поставил, id проставил. 
Возможно это очевидно, но все же прошу помочь) 
http://cssdeck.com/labs/1i8ehn3u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему просто неверные координаты были, вот я добавил 3 точки для левого луча звезды, все работает.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/dacw67cc

Comment: спасибо) координаты поначалу отсчитывал от родительского окна, т.е. .block